# Polymer. Way to dynamically add or remove observer

Tags: polymer

Is there a way to add or remove observer not in the moment of element initing?
I can define observer this way:

```
observers: ['dataChanged(data.*)']
```

Can i remove this observer later or can I set this observer different way than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily add an observer dynamically, either by:

```
this._addObserverEffect("property", observerFunction);
```

or

```
this._addComplexObserverEffect("dataChanged(data.*)");
```

Removing is harder and Polymer does not provide a function to do this. Although you could search for it in the `_propertyEffects` array, I wouldn't recommend it. Maybe just check in your observer function whether it should still be active, and return if not.

Answer (score 0):

you maybe can try this way:
configure your **data** property in the element with **notify: true**, so you can add a listener to changes with plain js

```
var element=document.querySelector("#YOUR-ELE-ID");
element.addEventListener("data-changed", function(e) {
 //triggered when data property changes
});
```

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#notify

and to remove the bound listener you can call `removeEventListener`

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Example 1 - plain JS :

```
document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
    var element=document.querySelector("#YOUR-ELE-ID");
    element.addEventListener("data-changed", function(e) {
     //triggered when data property changes
    });
});
```

Example 2 - in custom element:

```
//...element definition...
ready: function() {
    var element=document.querySelector("#YOUR-ELE-ID");
    element.addEventListener("data-changed", function(e) {
     //triggered when data property changes
    });
}
```