# Polymer 2. Way to dynamically add or remove observer

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Can anyone answer the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648192/polymer-way-to-dynamically-add-or-remove-observer), but related to Polymer 2?

The methods `_addObserverEffect` and `_addComplexObserverEffect` didn't survive in Polymer 2, for what I can see...

Comment: Please add more information what your problem is about.

Comment: I thought it was clear from the previous question, sorry! Simply, in Polymer 1 I could use this._addComplexObserverEffect("dataChanged(data.*)");, while in Polymer 2 it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `this._createPropertyObserver` and `this._createMethodObserver` function, but I haven't tested myself just found it in source code of rc.5 [element-mixin.html](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/v2.0.0-rc.5/lib/mixins/element-mixin.html) and [property-effects.html](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/9997a049ef092c55d324881892f850f6154e3fed/lib/mixins/property-effects.html).

Comment: I tried myself to read the code, but I don't understand how to use that: moreover, they look to be the simple (single property) observers, while I'm looking for the complex observers, possibly...

Comment: I think `_createMethodObserver` is for complex observers. I will try to provide an example.

Comment: @Andrea, have you tried `this._createMethodObserver('dataChanged(data.*)')`?

Comment: :-) It works, indeed: I cannot understand very well why, scrolling through the code, but I get the needed result! Thank you very much!

Comment: Super, you are welcome :). It works because this function is called for every observer in static property when objects is initialized.